# Can $n$ be negative for the infinite square well wave function $\psi_n(x)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, normalization

Consider the classic particle in a box example (infinite square well) in quantum mechanics:
\begin{equation}
\psi_n(x)=A\sin(k_n x),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
k_n=\frac{n \pi}{L}.
\end{equation}
I can easily see that $n=0$ is not a valid solution because of normalization but why would negative values for $n$ not be allowed? Can we not have 'negative' states like the $-4^{\textrm{th}}$ excited state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want our wavefunction basis to be normalized. That means the constant multiplying $\sin(k_{n}x)$, namely, $A_{n}$, must depend on $n$ (which  is why i added the subscript anyway).

Doing $n \rightarrow -n$ makes
$$
\phi_{n} = A_{n}\sin(k_{n}x) \rightarrow \phi_{-n} = -A_{-n}\sin(k_{n}x)
$$
since $\sin(k_{-n}x) = \sin(-\frac{n \pi}{L}) = - \sin(\frac{n \pi}{L}) = - \sin(k_{n}x)$.
Normalization will therefore impose the same condition of $A_{n}$ and $A_{-n}$ and therefore $\phi_{n}$ and $\phi_{-n}$ differ atmost by a phase. This means they are "equivalent" when building the basis and we need not consider $-n$ as a separate case.